# How to change position using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

I would like to change SCORE position from right to left and left to right or vise versa, but score position should not change . I tried several combinations and options but it didn't help.

**SIZE and WIDTH and  etc.... all are defined correctly, only we need to change the position of SCORE**

what I'm trying to do is:

Actual: **Left Score** | Left DIV       Middle DIV      Right DIV | **Right Score**

Expected: Left DIV | **Left Score**      Middle DIV      **Right Score** | Right DIV

or

Actual: Left DIV | **Left Score**      Middle DIV      Right DIV | **Right Score**

Expected: Right DIV | **Right Score**      Middle DIV     **Left Score** |Left DIV

or

Expected: Left DIV |**Left Score**    Middle DIV    **Right Score**|Right DIV

```css
div.team-info.team-pre-info.lpanel.Soccer 
div.team-info.team-final-in-info.lpanel.Soccer 
div.score-box.score-box-home.Soccer {
  float:right;
}

div.team-info.team-pre-info.rpanel.Soccer
div.team-info.team-final-in-info.rpanel.Soccer
div.score-box.score-box-home.Soccer {
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div style="color:#0000FF;width:500px">

  <div class="team-info team-pre-info lpanel Soccer" style="display:inline;">
  Left DIV </div>
    <div class="score-box score-box-home Soccer"  style="display:inline";> | Left Score</div>
   


 <div style="display:inline;">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Middle DIV&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  </div>



<div class="team-info team-pre-info rpanel Soccer"  style="display:inline;">
Right DIV   </div>
<div class="score-box score-box-way Soccer" style="display:inline"; >    
| Right Score </div>

  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wf2y7m01/

Comment: Why not just change the HTML...surely this isn't something CSS should be solving?

Comment: Have you looked into flexbox and order? https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/order/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tidy your markup first and get rid of the `display: inline`s. Then apply this concept:

Given

```
<div class="a">Left DIV</div>
<div class="a">Middle DIV</div>
<div class="a">Right DIV</div>
```

This makes them left-middle-right:

```
.a {
float: left;
width: 33%; /*or something else*/
}
```

And this right-middle-left:

```
.a {
float: right;
width: 33%; /*or something else*/
}
```

Comment: I'm only focusing on score. The score needs be inner side.

Comment: You can easily achieve that too with the same concept, floating the inner elements.